# how to toggle the full screen for webview inside android custom alert dialog?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-alertdialog, webchromeclient

> I have custom android alert dialog with android web view inside it and
>   other information.

**What i want:**

> I want to toggle the full screen of android web view for custom alert
>   dialog.

**P.S As full screen functionality is deprecated for web view on android 5.0 and above.**

Please suggest the best.

Comment: I would suggest you to create webview within an activity instead of alertdialog and set that particular activity to fullscreen.

Comment: ok.. but how to toggle the full screen for web view.

Comment: When the particular activity with WebView in initialized, it will be in already in fullscreen mode. If this is not what you meant, please explain further and  also add the relevant code.

Comment: though the activity is full screen but i have to show other content also, when the video is in full screen mode then other content will hide and for normal mode other content will show. so i need that toggling functionality for web view which will toggle the web view from normal mode to full screen mode.

Comment: Okay please add some source code